# How to run power shell script using different local admin count

Tags: windows-10, powershell, powershell-ise

In my computer, I have used 2 local administrator accounts which are inbuilt one(Admin1) and newly created one(Admin2). Both accounts are a member of the Administrator group.

I have a PowerShell script to create a restore point in my pc and user name and passwords are hardcoded to the script as below and it's working fine.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope "CurrentUser" -ExecutionPolicy "Unrestricted" -Force

$hostname = get-content env:computername
    
$username = "$hostname\Admin1"
$password = "Admin1@123"

$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force

$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $username, $securePassword


$command="

vssadmin Resize ShadowStorage /On=C: /For=C: /MaxSize=5GB

Enable-ComputerRestore -drive 'c:\'

Checkpoint-Computer -Description 'Inno GT Restore Point' -RestorePointType MODIFY_SETTINGS

Get-ComputerRestorePoint

Read-Host '
Restore Point Creation Successful
Press Enter key to leave...'

"

Start-Process Powershell.exe -Credential $credential -ArgumentList "-Command & {$command}"
```

Byt I need to run this script using another admin account and I have change credentials as follows.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope "CurrentUser" -ExecutionPolicy "Unrestricted" -Force
    
    $hostname = get-content env:computername
        
    $username = "$hostname\Admin2"
    $password = "Admin2@123"
    
    $securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
    
    $credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $username, $securePassword
    
    
    $command="
    
    vssadmin Resize ShadowStorage /On=C: /For=C: /MaxSize=5GB
    
    Enable-ComputerRestore -drive 'c:\'
    
    Checkpoint-Computer -Description 'Inno GT Restore Point' -RestorePointType MODIFY_SETTINGS
    
    Get-ComputerRestorePoint
    
    Read-Host '
    Restore Point Creation Successful
    Press Enter key to leave...'
    
    "
    
    Start-Process Powershell.exe -Credential $credential -ArgumentList "-Command & {$command}"
```

But it got error like this:

> [image]

I am not an expert in PowerShell, So I have change `Start-Process` part like this

```
Start-Process Powershell.exe -Verb RunAs -Credential $credential -ArgumentList "-Command & {$command}"
```

But after that, I got another error like this:

> [image]

Comment: The `-Verb` and `-Credential` parameters are competing, see empty output from `(Get-Command Start-Process).ParameterSets | Where-Object {  'Verb' -in $_.Parameters.Name -and 'Credential' -in $_.Parameters.Name } | FT -a`. Follow the hint in the 1st error message: _run this utility from an elevated command prompt_.

Comment: Never put plaintext credentials in a script. It's an unneeded risk. [There are tons of resources regarding securing credentials in PowerShell Scripts all over the web.](https://www.bing.com/search?q=%27powershell+secureing+credentials%27&form=ANNTH1&refig=0e4cb9fe945541ed9c5be97094e78658&sp=-1&pq=%27powershell+secureing+crede%27&sc=1-28&qs=n&sk=&cvid=0e4cb9fe945541ed9c5be97094e78658)

Comment: @JosefZ Buddy, I didn't get point and please clarify how to use ur code snippet inside my script?

Comment: @postanote Buddy, I got the risk. But that's my requirement.

Comment: Understood, gut you are physically entering the password, thus you have control of that. So, you can prompt for the creds you need to use, save that to a secure file, and call them from there. No more typing username and passwords in clear text, until those password change. This is more secure than in the script, but also has the risk of you keeping track of that file so no one can use the creds from it. Yet, in plain text, anyone can/will see them, in the script and on the wire. Yet, I do get that you are bound by your management. Yet, they must understand the risk. Especially in regulated.

Comment: Lastly, as for your statement ...  [I am not an expert in PowerShell...] --- this is really not expert level stuff, just normal info that is in the PowerShell help files and many places online. Just because you have not tried X or Y yet, does not mean it requires expert skills. Don't step on your own skills/knowledge. A deep look at the help files and the examples there and online will get you to where you want to be. We all have been there.

Comment: In other words: you can't use both `-Verb` and `-Credential` parameters in one `Start-Process` call as they belong to distinct parameter sets.  For proof, run `$cmdlet=(Get-Command Start-Process);
$cmdlet.Parameters.Verb.ParameterSets.Keys;
$cmdlet.Parameters.Credential.ParameterSets.Keys;`

Answer (score 0):

continuing from my comment... (always prompt for creds)

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope "CurrentUser" -ExecutionPolicy "Unrestricted" -Force

$Creds      = Get-Credential -Credential "$env:COMPUTERNAME\$env:USERNAME"

$command="
vssadmin Resize ShadowStorage /On=C: /For=C: /MaxSize=5GB

Enable-ComputerRestore -drive 'c:\'

Checkpoint-Computer -Description 'Inno GT Restore Point' -RestorePointType MODIFY_SETTINGS

Get-ComputerRestorePoint

Read-Host '
Restore Point Creation Successful
Press Enter key to leave...'
"
Start-Process Powershell.exe -Credential $Creds  -ArgumentList "-Command & {$command}"
```

***Update***

... and follow-up to my last comment to you about your stated use case.

This line...

```
Start-Process Powershell.exe -Verb RunAs -Credential $credential -ArgumentList "-Command & {$command}"
```

... should be written this way to work...

```
Start-Process powershell -Credential $credential -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -Command &{Start-Process cmd.exe -verb runas}'
```

Or try...

```
Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList "-NoExit","-NoProfile", "-Command  &{ cmd.exe }" -RunAs $credential
```

***Update as per my last comment***

```
Function Start-ConsoleCommand
{
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]

    [Alias('scc')]

    Param  
    ( 
        [string]$ConsoleCommand,
        [switch]$PoSHCore
    )

    If ($PoSHCore)
    {Start-Process pwsh -ArgumentList "-NoExit","-Command  &{ $ConsoleCommand }" -Wait}
    Else
    {Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList "-NoExit","-Command  &{ $ConsoleCommand }" -Wait}

}
```

Tweak as you need to.

Comment: Buddy both steps power shell not opening with provided credentials.

But using the below line, it can be run as my Admin2 account.

`Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList "-NoProfile", "-Command  &{ Start-Process powershell -verb RunAs }" -RunAs $credential`

But I stuck here because I need to run my code block ($command), on the newly opened admin mode PowerShell console.

Comment: I tried to change it like this but no luck :(

`Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList "-NoProfile", "-Command  &{ Start-Process powershell  -ArgumentList '-Command', $command -verb RunAs }" -RunAs $credential`

Please advice.

Comment: Buddy, with ur 2nd example I have call my code block as separate compiled exe and problem solved. Thank 4r all.

Comment: No worries, glad it got you going. Yet, having use PS2EXE (or other tools) to make it an executable, for it to work is just really odd. This also means that you could have saved it a .ps1 file and just called that as well. I wrote a function that I load via my profile for calling code in the manner described. Anyway, remember, that if it got you to your end results be sure to make this as your accepted answer for the befit of others who may find the same use case/scenario.

Comment: These work as written, as this the common way of doing this. I test all samples I post (when possible - depending on the use case and resources I have at hand at the time), before I ever post. So, I know these work. Once PS opens from either, just type whoami or $env:USERNAME to see what the session shows the identity.